# How to return using function/method?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, php

I'm interested for any language (PHP, C#, Java/script, etc..)...

Generally, when we want return from function, we use:

```
function parentFunc(){
  .....
  if (condition) {
    return ....
  }
  ....
}
```

However, I am interested if `return` is possible using a function, something like:

```
function parentFunc(){
  .....
  myCheck();
  ....
}

// inside `myCheck()`
function myCheck(){
   if(smth){
      Trigger_Parent_Return() .....   
   }
}
```

== EDIT ==
To downvoters - it a kinda unprofessionalism if you think that I dont know `if ($smth) return`. I am asking what I am asking - is that possible or not?

Comment: Exceptions kind of do this (you throw exception in myCheck and if not caught above - it triggers parent "return").

Comment: @Evk it rather skips the return, doesn't it

Comment: It's possible by for instance having the inner function return `true` or `false`, and do `if (myCheck()) return;` But I guess you already knew that?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks but ya, out of question. I am asking what i am asking.

Comment: I'm not aware of any function-based approach to this. The only thing that comes to mind is a language that has some form of `GOTO`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like prototypical inheritance to be honest. The only language I know of that can do this is Javascript.

Take the following snippit for example.

```
function extend(){
var returnFunc =  function(Name, Obj){};
return returnFunc;
}

var newFunc = new extend();
var func = new newFunc(“hello”, {test: 0});
```

Answer (score -1):

The following is the example of your problem

```
function parentFunc(){
  returnData = myCheck();
  if(returnData)
  {
     //do your task
  }
}

function myCheck(){
   if(smth){
      return true;
   }
}
```